# how i do extract .text(data) value to put it inside conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do here is to disable a button when a username exists. otherwise, the button is enabled. i'm not adept at javascript/jquery, so I might need a tiny help. any would be appreciated:

```
$('#username2').keyup(function() {
    var username = $(this).val();
    $('#username_status').text('searching....');
    if(username2 != "") {
        $.post('username_check.php',{username2:username}, function(data) {
            $('#username_status').text(data);
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#username_status').text('Nothing');
    }



    if ($('#username_status').text(data) != 'Username available!') {
        $("#btnSignUp").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
         $("#btnSignUp").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

i'm guessing the way i did my conditional statement is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It should be.

```
$('#username_status').text()
```

This will give you the correct textual content

```
if ($('#username_status').text() != 'Username available!') {

    $("#btnSignUp").prop("disabled", false);

} else {

     $("#btnSignUp").prop("disabled", true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the check inside the AJAX request:

```
$('#username2').keyup(function() {
    var username = $(this).val();
    if(username != "") {
        $('#username_status').text('searching....');
        $.post('username_check.php',{username2:username}, function(data) {
            $('#username_status').text(data);
            $("#btnSignUp").prop("disabled", data != 'Username available!');
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#username_status').text('Nothing');
        $("#btnSignUp").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can keep the button disabled by default.

```
<input id="btnSignUp" name="btnSignUp" disabled="disabled" type="button" value="Sign Up" />
```

If the user name is available, you can enable it by

```
$("#btnSignUp").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Also you can get compare Strings as below

```
$("#username_status").val() != 'Username available!'
```

Comment: if he isn't using an input control .val() won't really work. i'm guessing he is using a div or similar which is why he used .text()

Comment: Actually, He dont need to put the AJAX response in div.He can directly compare the response.

Comment: He currently uses the div to provide feedback when the request starts off ..i don't think thats a bad idea :)

Comment: Don't use `.removeAttr('disabled')`. That's what `.prop` is for.